# Configuring SNMP Agent and Manager with JAVA

Tags: java, networking, snmp, snmp4j

I want to manage and monitor the devices on the network by using SNMP. I need a Java program that shows every device's status and every trap(if there's any). I'll start to  coding but I couldn't find any good, explanatory resource about the topic. I'm new at whole SNMP thing, but i did some research, read articles. I don't know where to start. I found a resource: [for creating SNMP agent](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/snmp/creating-snmp-agent-server-in-java-using-snmp4j/). However it's only for one computer. I want to reach the whole network by using SNMP. Do i need to download any program to the devices i want to manage?

Please someone explain where do i have to start, what do i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

The link that you provided is used for the creating the *SNMP Manager*, although they call it "agent" in the description. This program will run on the machine you would like to use to manage your other SNMP devices (or "agents") from. On every machine that you would like to manage, you will need to run some kind of SNMP Agent software to configure the traps that are set as well as where to send the data. This article, http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/snmp/create-snmp-client-in-java-using-snmp4j/, from the same blog is the software used on the managed machines.

Comment: So, you're saying the code in the link i provided will run on the manager and the link you provided will run on the agents. However, in SNMP "client" means manager. I still think this SNMPAgent code must run on the agents and the code in the link you provided must run on the manager. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I also wonder that what "running the program on the machine" means. I run these codes in the Eclipse IDE. If i run "the agent code" on some machine and "the manager code" on another machine, then how will they connect? Will i run them some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Java SNMP agent is the one who will accept the request from the SNMP manager and send the response back to the Java SNMP manager. SNMP manager may be third party software or java code.

Source: You can visit the below link to know, how to implement java SNMP agent.

[Java SNMP Manager | bytesofgigabytes.com](http://www.bytesofgigabytes.com/snmp-protocol/java-snmp-agent/)

You can also write your own SNMP manager using java code which will request the OID to the SNMP agent and receives the response back from the SNMP agent.

Source: You can visit the below link to know, how to implement java SNMP Manager.

[Java SNMP manager | bytesofgigabytes.com](http://www.bytesofgigabytes.com/snmp-protocol/java-snmp-manager/)